# How do I "suggest edit" when I have enough rep to edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I have enough reputation to edit questions on SO. However, sometimes, I'd like to suggest to the OP a significant revision. For example, on [Pointer unitialized in the main functtion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67168489/pointer-unitialized-in-the-main-function) , I would have trimmed the code down to like 20 lines that showed the issue right away.

It would probably still have been closed "caused by a typo", but still, I wanted to show the OP what I thought a smaller, more useful, question could be.

But I don't want my edit to be seen as vandalizing the question, so I'm not willing to that significantly trim it myself. Is there a button I missed to "suggest edit", when you could actually edit ?

Comment: There is a button for that. It should be labeled with the text: "Add a comment".

Comment: I get your point, and I did comment on that question. But the "add a comment" box is small, doesn't allow all the markup and very easily gets hidden by other comments. I also doesn't give you a space to actually put the whole edit.

Comment: I have done this using pastebin.com, asking them to look at my proposal linking to the pastebin in a comment. It's not possible to make a suggested edit with more than 2K reputation points. I wish there was a way to opt-in to "privileges", but unfortunately they are pressed upon us. Your other option is to create a new account and keep that with low reputation points.

Comment: that is clearly an answer and would helped the user enourm, so next time answer it and close it for  a typo, so that other who find it can be helped

Comment: That's an interesting request, btw (maybe reformat it as a [tag:feature-request]?). Although a viable solution now is just to comment, an ability to suggest edits for peers to vote on (without gaining rep for these suggestions - to avoid rep farming practices) is not without its merit - I would support it if it is an opt-in feature.

Comment: I don't see the problem with simply editing. There is a reason for rep threshold for privileges. You are trusted enough to use your privilege, why wouldn't you want to use it? If you think that edit improves the question - just do it. Then comment to the OP something like "Please check my edit to your question, this is how it should look". If they don't like it - they are free to rollback...